# Batch file ancorado

Tags: batch, backup

Como consigo fazer que um batch fique ancorado em uma pasta para uma operação de backup em um pendrive na qual a letra da unidade sempre muda exemplo:

```
@echo off
mkdir ..\subs
move /y .\*.srt ..\subs
pause
exit
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com ancorado?

Comment: não sei o porque mas quando vc simplesmente executa o bat o cmd executa partir da pasta de usuário `c:\users\joao` e não da pasta na qual se encontra o bat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) para alterar o [diretório de trabalho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), passe [`%~dp0`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) para indicar o diretório do arquivo `.bat`, veja um exemplo:

```
@echo off

echo Diretorio atual %cd%
echo Diretorio do script %~dp0

REM Altera o diretório atual de trabalho
pushd %~dp0

echo Diretorio atual %cd%
pause
```

Ao usar `pushd %~dp0` você indica que o diretório atual é o local onde o arquivo está localizado.

Saída:

> ```
> Diretorio atual C:\Users\<usuario>
> Diretorio do script C:\Users\<usuario>\local\do\batch\
> Diretorio atual C:\Users\<usuario>\local\do\batch\
>
> Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
> ```

Answer (score 0):

O pendrive tem que ter alguma marca para ser checada. Pode ser assim:
Você cria a pasta \subs no pendrive que vai usar para backup e coloca o código abaixo na pasta.

```
@echo off
if EXIST d:\subs\*.srt set PENDRIVE=D:&goto backup
if EXIST e:\subs\*.srt set PENDRIVE=E:&goto backup
if EXIST f:\subs\*.srt set PENDRIVE=F:&goto backup
if EXIST g:\subs\*.srt set PENDRIVE=G:&goto backup
rem Acrescente outros Drives se quiser
echo NENHUM PENDRIVE ENCONTRADO.
goto fim
:backup
move /y .\*.srt %PENDRIVE%\subs
:fim
pause
```